# Creating a link with two selections

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I have two selections and I want to create a link with the values from both. But the problem is that if I make selection changes, the link doesn't refresh.

```
const seOne = $('select[name=selectionOne] option').filter(':selected').val();
const seTwo = $('select[name=selectionTwo] option').filter(':selected').val();
if (seOne != null && seTwo != null) {
        const goThereButton = document.getElementById("goThereButton");
        goThereButton.textContent = "View";
        goThereButton.classList.remove("btn-secondary");
        goThereButton.classList.add("btn-primary");
        goThereButton.href = appLink + 'page?scd=content&id=' + seOne + '&hsg=' + seTwo;
}
```

How can I refresh the link when the selection changes?

Comment: Did you try wrapping this in onchange event on both the select?

Comment: the code you show is insufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the change event and test after that. Plus, with jQuery, you can chain all those functions on the `#goThereButton`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name=selectionOne], select[name=selectionTwo]').change(function() {
    let v1 = $('select[name=selectionOne]').val(), v2 = $('select[name=selectionTwo]').val();
    if (v1 && v2) $("#goThereButton").text("View").removeClass("btn-secondary").addClass("btn-primary").attr('href', appLink + 'page?scd=content&id=' + v1 + '&hsg=' + v2);
  });
})
```

Comment: @Emre7 - FYI: I updated the answer to be more optimized - you can chain all those jQuery functions